# String Comparison And Alphabetic Order of Individual Characters

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I have a question related to string comparison vs. character comparison.

Characters `>` and `0` (zero) have following decimal values `62` and `48` accordingly.

When I compare two characters in the following code, I get value `True` (which is correct)

```
Console.WriteLine('>' > '0');
```

When I compare two one-character strings in the following code, I get value `-1` which indicates that *">" is less than "0"* (default culture is English)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(">", "0"));
```

Whereas comparison of "3" and "1" (`51` and `49` code values) in the following code returns `1` (as expected)

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare("3", "1"));
```

Also, `string.Compare(string str1, string str2)` documentation says:

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific
>   information such as casing rules and the alphabetic order of
>   individual characters

Would you be able to explain (or provide reference to some documentation) how string comparison is implemented e.g. how *alphabetic order of individual characters* is calculated etc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you compare the characters `'>'` and `'0'`, you are comparing their ordinal values.

To get the same behaviour from a string comparison, supply the ordinal string comparison type:

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(">", "0", StringComparison.Ordinal));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(">", "0", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(">", "0", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
```

The current culture is used by default, which has a sorting order intended to sort strings 'alphabetically' rather in strictly lexical order, for some definition of alphabetically.

Answer (score 26):

The sort order of strings depends on the culture you use.

[StringComparer.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentculture.aspx) sorts the following 1-character strings as follows on my machine:

```
' -   ! " # $ % & (  ) * , . / : ; ? @ [
\ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ +  < = > 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 a A b B c C d  D e E f F g G h H i
I j J k K l L m M n  N o O p P q Q r R s
S t T u U v V w W x  X y Y z Z
```

[StringComparer.Ordinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx) sorts the same strings as follows:

```
  ! " # $ % & ' ( )  * + , - . / 0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < =  > ? @ A B C D E F G
H I J K L M N O P Q  R S T U V W X Y Z [
\ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e  f g h i j k l m n o
p q r s t u v w x y  z { | } ~
```

Comment: You fail to inform us what your current culture is, and that is a shame. I can say that it is not `"fy-NL"` (West Frisian (Netherlands)), because then the letter `y` would be next to the `i`. Also, it can't be `"et-EE"` (Estonian (Estonia)), for then the `z` would be next to the `s`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want is the comparison to not use culture-specific rules. Have you tried StringComparison.Ordinal:

```
Console.WriteLine( string.Compare( ">", "0", StringComparison.Ordinal ) ); // returns a positive number
```

Answer (score 1):

it returns `-1` because it is comparing `str2` to `str1`, not the other way around. Eg, "is 48 equal to 62". No, it's less than 62 so it returns -1. It's semantically a little confusing when you read the parameter order

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx) says "String.Compare(strA, strB) - Less than zero - strA is less than strB." For example, `string.Compare("A", "B")` returns `-1` - `"A"` is less than `"B"`. Why is `">"` less than `"0"`?

Comment: I've updated my question: when you compare "3" to "1" you get value `1` where "3" has code 51 and "1" has code 49 (as expected). So that does not match with your explanation.

Comment: @Alexandar good point. I think PeteKirkham answered it better than I did