# How does OrderBy work with regard to strings in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this code

```
var strings2 = new List<string>
    {
        "0", // Ascii code 48 (decimal)
        "|"  // Ascii code 125 (decimal)
    };
var sorted = strings2.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Sorted contains `"|", "0"`. Now consider this code (all I did was change `"|"` to `"."`)

```
var strings2 = new List<string>
    {
        "0", // Ascii code 48 (decimal)
        "."  // Ascii code 46 (decimal)
    };
var sorted = strings2.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Now sorted contains `".", "0"`
In both cases the `"0"` comes at the end even though 125 > 48, what is going on here?

Comment: ASCII numerical codes do not necessarily equate to the sort order of characters in a string. Many different factors go into determining sort order, especially the current culture of the executing program.

Comment: What does equate to the sort order then?

Comment: I'm not an expert but you're using strings (delimited by double quotes `"`) not chars (delimited by single quotes `'`). As @Sam mentions, it's probably got something to do with it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order [depends on the culture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14967721/2589202) that you use.

You can pass the culture in an overload to OrderBy.

```
var sorted = strings2.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 8):

Here you go:

> The comparison uses the current culture to obtain culture-specific
>   information such as casing rules and the **alphabetic order of
>   individual characters**. For example, a culture could specify that
>   certain combinations of characters be treated as a single character,
>   or uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a particular way,
>   or that the sorting order of a character depends on the characters
>   that precede or follow it.

[Source: String.Compare Method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The ".OrderBy" function utilizes the default comparer for a string. That comparer is not necessarily going to return a sort order based on the ASCII code.

For a list of all the different string comparers, see the article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx).