# Is sorting in LINQ by Ascii code?

Tags: c#, linq

In my LINQ to Entities query I have a `.orderby f.Description.Trim()` command
The reason for `.Trim()` is that some of the data coming from DB have a bunch of white spaces at the beginning of them so I wanted to trim those so they won't affect sorting.

Now it sorts correctly but I see something like this in the result:

```
[Queries - Blah]
Action
Adhere
Azalia
```

Then I looked up `ASCII` code of `"["` and it is 91 and "A" is 65 so how come that one showed up first? Maybe there are some other things in the code causing this and sort is fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does OrderBy work with regard to strings in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700300/how-does-orderby-work-with-regard-to-strings-in-c)

Comment: @Zack no, this is LINQ to Entities, which will execute on the database, not in C#.

Comment: Linq to entities is just converting your query into SQL, the sorting will be as per the underlying database engine.

Comment: could you change `[` to `{` and then give me request? i think that then the `{` will be last.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OrderBy is using the default comparator for strings, which doesn't use ASCII (actually, Unicode) ordinal comparison.  It actually depends on the current culture you are using.

And, if you think about it... if you were sorting entries for an appendix or index, symbols come before letters (at least in English).

If you want to sort by "raw ascii value", use

```
...OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.Ordinal)
```

Answer (score 5):

If the actual expression can be compiled to a store expression, then the ordering will be done as implemented by your store.

So: the result will depend on the collation of the database, table and column.

Comment: " (the code you display does not compile), " ? Hmm? It did compile and worked and showed them in the order I posted!

Comment: Or remove the `.` prefix?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer does not apply to LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: Yes, it does.  The fact that he is using Trim() negates this being able to be offloaded to the SQL server.