# c# list strings with containing numbers orderby

Tags: c#, list, sorting, observablecollection

I have a list of strings of distances which goes like follows:

1.3 km 
20 km
44 km
22.5 km
26.7 km

Currently I am ordering them by length and then "alphabetically" with:

> listofdistances.OrderBy(x => x.Distance.Length).ThenBy(x =>
>   x.Distance)

This will give me a list ordered as follows: 
20 km 
44 km 
1.3 km
22.5 km
26.7 km

That is what the code does and I understand it. Now i would like a solution to sort the strings by actual distances, but i dont know how to achieve it:
1.3 km
20 km 
22.5 km
26.7 km
44 km

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can control the order of the strings by setting the [culture in an overload of `OrderBy`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22700387/2589202).  You may need to create your own culture.

Comment: Maybe it would be a better idea to store the distances in a class that has a unit and a value property. Maybe this class is also able  to convert between units so that it is even able to sort a list correctly that mixes meters, kilometers and miles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a natural sort equality comparer.

```
public class DistanceNaturalSort : IComparer<string>
{

    int IComparer<string>.Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        try
        {
            var valX = double.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value);
            var valY = double.Parse(Regex.Match(y, @"\d+(\.\d+)?").Value);
            if (valX == valY)
                return 0;
            else if (valX < valY)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return ((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare(y, x));
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you just pass in your comparer to the first order by:

```
var comparer = new DistanceNaturalSort();
var sorted = listofdistances.OrderBy(x => x, comparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in Linq also

```
  string[] h = new string[] { "1.3 km","20 km","44 km","22.5 km","26.7 km" };
 h.Select(g => double.Parse(g.Trim().Split(' ')[0])).OrderBy(g => g).Select(x => x + " Km")>toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is a split of space always and unit is always same

```
var v = ls.Select(x => x.Split(' '));
var v2 = v.OrderBy(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x[0]));
var v3 =  v2.Select(z=>z.Aggregate((x, y) => x.ToString() + " " + y));
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly refer the following, 
 I think the one you are looking for.

The [`Alphanum Algorithm`](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)

&

The [`Java Comparator Implementation`](http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java).